# What does `--auth-type login` mean in Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli, azure-iot-hub-device-management

What does `--auth-type login` mean in Azure CLI?
According to the documentation, it `Indicates whether the operation should auto-derive a policy key or use the current Azure AD session`.

The command below is an example to get a list of devices in IoT Hub.
But it fails with the authorization error.

```sh
$ az iot hub device-identity list -n {hub name} --auth-type login
{'Message': '{"errorCode":401003,"trackingId":"trackingIdhere","message":"Principal live.com#myemailaddress@example.com is not authorized for POST on /devices/query due to no assigned permissions","timestampUtc":"2021-05-31T13:16:16.2433062Z"}', 'ExceptionMessage': ''}
```

Without `--auth-type login` (which means `--auth-type key` by default), however, it successfully completes the execution.

It is strange that `--auth-type login` gives authorization error because I am logged in as an owner of the resource.
Maybe I misunderstand the purpose of `--auth-type login`.

So what does `--auth-type login` mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, when you login using `--auth-type login` you're using logged-in user principal's token. Make sure you have the [right permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-azure-ad-rbac) to the IoTHub.

This is what I found on the Az Cli updates on [Azure's Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension/blob/dev/HISTORY.rst):

> Most commands against IoT Hub support Azure AD based access. The type of auth used to execute commands can be controlled with the "--auth-type" parameter which accepts the values "key" or "login". The value of "key" is set by default.
> When "--auth-type" has the value of "key", like before the CLI will auto-discover a suitable policy when interacting with iothub.
> When "--auth-type" has the value "login", an access token from the Azure CLI logged in principal will be used for the operation.

Owner role should be more than sufficient. If you recently assigned the role via RBAC, try to do an `az logout` followed by an `az login` to see if it helps. I've seen many similar issues related to just minor delays in role propagation. However, your issue could be different. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-401003-iothubunauthorized) which gives some interesting insights as to what could be happening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I re-logined but did not work. Actually i am not just an owner of the resource but a global administrator (I created my tenant for my personal project).

Comment: Ok sorry I might not be able to help much but I hopefully I give you some pointers. Can you try this: `az iot hub device-identity list -n new-iot --auth-type login --debug` and examine the output (specially right after the first response headers), see if you find anything unusual in the request specially. I also had closer look at your error and that error id (401003) mentions something mentions some authorization issue.

Comment: I have no idea why but assigning `IoT Hub Data Contributor` role did the trick. But the principal i am logged in as in azcli is global admin, so this role seems redundant...

Comment: Try to remove the role and see if it still works! I agree that it doesn't make sense. Hopefully it just needed a jumpstart.

Comment: I am the only one user in my tenant and i don't know if I can remove the global admin role from the first place...

Comment: I also tried assigning owner or contributor in addition to IoT hub data contributor and it still worked. But without IoT Hub data contributor and with owner or contributor it did not work. It might be a bug or related to what is mentioned in the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-azure-ad-rbac#azure-ad-access-from-azure-portal)